# Reloading Clojure code in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, clojure

I have an existing Java webapp running in Tomcat to which I'm adding some primitive Clojure support. For the time being, I'm just including Clojure source files as resources on the classpath and invoking it through `clojure.lang.RT`. It's primitive, but works fine.

However, I've noticed that Tomcat's `WebappClassLoader` caches resources retrieved through `getResourceAsInputStream()` which Clojure uses to retrieve and compile source code. That is, doing `(require 'my-ns :reload)` just reloads the cached version of the file even though an updated one is available on disk. Is there a way to circumvent or avoid this caching for Clojure files?

The best I've come up with after much fruitless googling is to use reflection to manually remove the entry from `WebappClassLoader.resourceEntries` which is *awful*.

I must be missing something.

Answers like "use Jetty/Glassfish/JBoss", "restart Tomcat", etc aren't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to circumvent `WebappClassLoader`'s behaviour there.  What you *can* do is move the code that's being loaded outside of its jurisdiction; e.g. up to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

You'll need to move all of your dependencies there as well, leaving the .war file you actually deploy as a webapp as a small shell that expects all the code to already be available elsewhere.

This will get you out of `WebappClassLoader`'s jurisdiction, and hopefully its semantics as well.  (If it caches things loaded from parent classloaders, that would seem thoroughly broken IMO.)

Comment: Thanks Chas. I'll have to think about this a bit. Putting stuff in `lib` isn't that convenient.  I wonder if `*use-context-classloader*` would have an affect without screwing up other stuff.

Comment: @DaveRay `*use-context-classloader*` is true by default. Setting it to false will cause loads to route through the ClassLoader that loaded Clojure itself — which will either not have any effect (if Clojure was loaded from the webapp) or cause breakage (i.e. if you put clojure.jar in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` but try to load code from a webapp).

Q: why not just start up a REPL server from the webapp, connect to it, and load code with abandon that way?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm just not creative enough in how I'd use a REPL server for this :) Say I have a bunch of code across several files on disk. I start up Tomcat with the repl server running, how do I get all that code up there?

Comment: The details vary depending on your tool of choice, but the workflow is generally (a) connect to the REPL; (b) open/switch to the file you want to load; (c) command your tool to send the file to the connected REPL.  Counterclockwise, SLIME, nrepl.el, vimclojure, Enclojure, and surely other tools all support this kind of workflow.  Feel free to ping me in irc if you want to discuss at length. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the Clojure source files under `WEB-INF`? Then you can read them using http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

`servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/foo/core.clj");`

This worked for me in the past to load un-cached Groovy classes from source in Tomcat.

Comment: It seems like that would work if I could get `clojure.lang.RT` to load files that way. Otherwise, `(require 'foo :reload)` would continue to use the context class loader.

Answer (score 0):

Is this related to the `cachingAllowed` flag as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)? Just shooting into the blue.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a patched version of clojure which does something along the lines:

```
(io/input-stream (io/resource "bla.clj"))
```

I found a remark on the net that this is not cached.

Comment: `(io/resource)` uses the context class loader so it'll go through Tomcat and be cached. :(

Comment: @dave-ray I found claims that `.getResource` (used by `io/resource`) is not cached. By I don't know Tomcat. On my side, this is all guessing anyway. :]